# Get result of formula as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, export

I have an Excel doc which populates a matrix using formula, for example;

```
 |  A  |  B  |  C  
1|=1+2 |=2+2 |     
2|     |     |=4-1
```

would display as;

```
 |  A  |  B  |  C  
1|3    |4    |     
2|     |     |3
```

I then want to export the results to a CSV file. I found a guide online to [export just a selection of a sheet to a CSV file](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76720), but obviously this exports to the file as;

```
 |  A  |  B  |  C  
1|=1+2 |=2+2 |     
2|     |     |=4-1
```

I probably used a bad example as in my problem the formula reference another sheet in the workbook so throws a `#REF!` error.

Is there any way I can export / copy the result of the formula instead of the formula itself?

Comment: Is the dataset small enough to just select the area you want to create as a CSV then `Copy` and `Paste Special` - `Values` into a new sheet, then save that sheet as CSV?

Comment: The dataset varies in size and it is possible but I am trying to automate the process as the action is performed over a large number of workbooks. You have got me thinking though, I wonder if there is a `Paste Special` option in `VBA`. Will look into that.

Comment: Select the entire page, and copy. In a new worksheet, right click,  paste special -> values only. Export this worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after Tyson got me thinking about Paste Special, I found out that you can do this in VBA;

```
Sub testexport()
     '
     ' export Macro

    Range("B20:AA45").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\!LOCAL_STORE\Book2.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't use VBA often, but that looks to me like it's probably changing the original selection, and that re-saving the entire wookbook will wipe your formulas.  If your looking to automate then you could just paste special to a new sheet from within VBA, save and then delete the new sheet to cleanup.